# Is there a SQL Server function type that doesn't return anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a SQL Server function that doesn't return anything but rather simply updates based on some input.

Looking at the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), there doesn't seem to be a function like this?

How can I acheive this behaviour?

Basically, I need a function type that I can exec at anytime to do some updating.

Like:

`exec UpdateData 'derp'`

Comment: Use a stored procedure?

Comment: Running DML statements is not at all possible in SQL Server. Why dont you go for a Stored Procedure instead?

Comment: This is from within a stored procedure already, but I will need to execute.....damn, im being an idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), is a "type" of function, and it is usually used for situations just like yours, to modify some date when executed.

You can pass it parameters, `'derp'`, and create some SQL logic to update your records. In the end the stored procedure will just `execute` and won't return anything (actually, you can return information but it's not the topic of your question).

Answer (score 2):

Create a stored procedure

e.g.

```
Create Procedure usp_UpdateDate

@Id int,
@Value varchar(100)

AS

Update TableName
Set Data= @Value
Where Id = @Id
```

Then you can

```
exec usp_UpdateDate 1,'value to update'
```